# saving hi resolution images in Couchbase lite

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I am taking a photo and saving as an image in cache. I also name the image and save the name to find later.

```
if ((requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

        //save photo
        Date dTime = new Date();
        String pictureName = String.valueOf(dTime.getTime()).substring(1,10);
        // saved in internal program cache storage
        String extr = getCacheDir().toString();
        File myPath = new File(extr, "DVIR");

        if (!myPath.exists()) {
            myPath.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath + "/" + pictureName + ".png");
            assert photo != null;
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    photo, myPath.getPath(), pictureName + ".png");

            photos.add(pictureName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Getting image and saving as document attachment, image names are stored in photos[] array.

```
try {
        assert document != null;
        document.putProperties(properties);
        if(photos.size()>0) {
            String pName;
            for(int i=0;i<photos.size();i++){
                pName = photos.get(i);
                UnsavedRevision newRev = document.getCurrentRevision().createRevision();
                newRev.setAttachment(pName + ".png", "image/png", getphotoFromStorage(pName));
                newRev.save();
            }

        }
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Save Failed" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When i retrieve photo a 400px wide image is pixelated.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I'm confused.  Is there something that makes you think this is an issue with Couchbase Lite?  As far as CBL is concerned, the image is just a binary blob, so it isn't messing with the compression or anything.  Have you checked to see the image isn't being changed by the other processing you're doing (photo.compress or MediaStore)?

Comment: I am not sure what part of the process is reducing the resolution. That  reminds me about how i am viewing the image. I am viewing the image in a web app that uses angularjs and pouchdb to retrieve the image from couchbase server.  How can i check the size or view the image in the middle of the process?  Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'd start by using inspection tools to see how big the image actually is when rendered in the browser.  This seems the most likely issue.  Otherwise I would check the size in bytes of the image at various points.  The second most likely issue I'd guess is with what's being returned by getPhotoFromStorage.  Your photo may not have been stored the way you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As the other commentors have surmised, the problem is unrelated to Couchbase. The documentation for [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) states that only

> a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field.

To get the full sized image back you need to pass the location that you want the Intent to write image. This has the happy side-effect of making your code much simpler. You can simple open a FileInputStream and pass that to Couchbase.